# Small differences in writing between very different words

Tags: difference, spelling

The interest is to me that two such different concepts such as "book" and "boot" or "kill" and "will" are written so similarly.

*In my language*, book is knjiga and boot is čizma; they have almost nothing in common.

How the English is so much similarity, what is meant by **two letters o o** and whether it has the meaning of the **letters k and t.**

Comment: "Letters" (actually the sounds represented by the letters) have no independent "meaning" which they contribute to the "meaning" of the word. The sound of a word is unrelated to its meaning, except in the case of a few imitative words like *moo* and *cough*.

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: My language is Serbian

Comment: There are no pairs of words in Serbian that differ by only one or two characters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rests on the invalid assumption that the phonological components of a word have independent meaning.

Comment: @stoneyb But surely this invalid assumption is the whole point of the question. If someone asks, "Is such-and-such true?", surely we would not say that that is a good and valid question if the answer is yes, but an invalid question that should be closed if the answer is no.

Comment: Read the first paragraph (and beyond if you like) of [**Alphabet - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet). As for the question, the OP makes an assumtion without any valid backing or reference to support it.

Comment: @Jay This is the same sort of question as those which ask for the meaning of typos, which we routinely close because they aren't real questions. OP does not ask whether 'oo' is meaningful; he assumes it is meaningful and asks for its meaning.

Comment: @StoneyB "does not ask whether 'oo' is meaningful" Sure. So there's no valid direct answer to his question. But we can reasonably reply "your question is based on an invalid assumption" and explain. But that's true of many questions. People often ask "which of these two alternatives is correct", and we reply "neither, the correct way to say this is ...", etc.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that can look funny when you're learning English.

But surely you have words in Croatian that look or sound similar but have very different meanings. Like "febra" is an illness, while "februar" is a month on the calendar. Or "drijen" is a kind of tree, while "drijem" is sleep.

Comment: > _I suppose that can look funny when you're learning English_. @Jay, Similarly acts English as a language that is frivolous or children's language
So it seems to me, to make it better understood, try to understand the concepts of a word as the word got.

Comment: I like this answer; it highlights that this is a thing in **every language**. In Japanese, *shujin* means husband while *shuujin* means prisoner; *kankoku* refers to Korea while *kangoku* refers to prison. In Spanish, *caballo* means horse and *cabello* means hair.

Comment: @eric Those may not be the best examples. As a divorced man, I see a lot of similarity between the concept of "husband" and "prisoner". :-)

Comment: @Jay Fair enough--but did you also go to get your horse cut regularly? ;)

Answer (score 5):

In many cases, the spelling of English words has to do with where they were taken from, and when they entered the language. For instance, with "book" and "boot", "book" entered the English language from the proto-German, a very long time ago. If it had come from a Latin-based language, like most of western Europe, it would have had "lib-" as a root ("libro" is Spanish for book, "libre" is French, they are both drawn from the Latin "libellus"; "library" entered the English language much later and draws from this same root). "Boot" comes from the Old French "bote". Their meanings are unrelated because their sources are unrelated. It is common, but not universal, that English words from the same sources that sound similar will have similar roots and related meanings.

This is an example of false cognates within a single language.

If this topic interests you, I highly recommend spending some time perusing [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com)